# iPhone Bluetooth Communication Examples

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, bluetooth

I've been trying to find examples on communicating with bluetooth devices on iOS and have been coming up short. As I understand it SPP is not yet supported. At the simplest level, I'd like to send a simple 1 or 0 signal to the bluetooth device I'm creating. (It's a bluetooth switch that would turn something on and off). Is there a way to cleverly do this through the HID or HFP profiles?

Answer (score 4):

The short answer to your question is that [you can't connect to an arbitrary Bluetooth device](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1657/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010232) you may happen to have, you can only connect to a Bluetooth device that has come through Apple's licensing program (i.e. the "Made for iPod/iPhone" label). From Apple's documentation:

> **Q:** [The External Accessory framework allows] my application to communicate with Bluetooth devices. So why doesn't my application see the Bluetooth accessory sitting next to my iPhone?
> **A:** The External Accessory framework is designed to allow iOS applications to communicate only with hardware accessories that are developed under Apple's MFi licensee program.

So there is no *public API* for accessing an arbitrary Bluetooth device from within iOS: you have to go through the External Accessory Framework to communicate via Bluetooth, and the EAF's mission is "communicate with MFi devices," not "communicate with arbitrary external devices." A sufficiently ingenious developer could probably hack something in there, but -

- it's a non-trivial undertaking
- you are spectacularly unlikely to get past the App Store approval process

So there's just not much percentage in it - the effort of doing so is unlikely to reward you.

If there already exists an MFi device that can be coerced into doing something that you want, that's probably your best chance - short of going through the MFi approval/licensing process yourself, of course. If you want to do so, have at it and good luck.

I'm answering this question late because Zeroxide's answer is incorrect (you can use a random Bluetooth keyboard with your iOS device because *Apple* implemented that connection, which is different from giving you a public API path to doing likewise) and I find Rokridi's answer to be incomplete-though-headed-in-the-right-direction.

**Edit:** A caveat has since been added to the linked Apple page about [Bluetooth Low-Energy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth_low_energy) devices. So there's a loophole, but it's not a big one because very, very few Bluetooth LE devices have actually been produced as yet.

Comment: The above quoted Technical Q&A QA1657 article also states: "Bluetooth low energy accessories do not interface with the External Accessory framework and are NOT REQUIRED TO BE MFi compliant. Instead, apps use the CoreBluetooth framework to communicate with Bluetooth low energy accessories from iOS or OS X."

Answer (score 2):

As far as i know, if your external device is non iOs device then you should use External Accessory Framework to communicate your application with it. Threfore, you external device should be certified by Apple through the Made for Ipod program (MFI). Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know of any examples of using this framework?

Comment: Check this link https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/search/?q=eaaccessory. You will find documentation about the External accessory Framework. Apple also provides a sample demo to show how to establish a connection with an external accessory. The sample compiles and runs however you need an external device if you want to test the functionnalities of the given example.If you have any question or information about this framework please contact me because i recently began developping an application that is based on this framework.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use classic Bluetooth (not BLE), then you have to first PAIR the iOS device to the Bluetooth device (in Settings). If you can't do that then you can't communicate with it with your app.

Comment: I have paired my bluetooth keyboard with iPhone, it is working fine. Then, How can I search and get the device details using ExternalAccessoryFramework

Answer (score -1):

NO. whether device is MFi certified or not, you can connect device to iphone if bluetooth profile is HFP, or HID's (ordinary profiles. not iAP profile). Think about bluetooth headset or keyboard. does it need MFi mark on it to use? NO. Never.

Comment: That's actually incorrect: there's a big difference between what iOS itself will see and acknowledge and what your application is allowed to see.

Comment: @Zeroxide : Do you have any sample code for connect with external device ?

Comment: @Zeroxid : How can you connect to and external device with HID bluetooth profile? . HID profile is used for keyboard input. MFi program must need a MFi certified device to establish connection and further communication. Other wise target device must be Low Energy, then you can use CoreBluetooth framework for communication.